# Error when importing react component from a git repo dependancy: Element type is invalid

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build react shared ui component library and add it as a dependency in another react project (created with create-react-app). However, I am getting an error when I try to import the Button component. Reading similar questions, it looks like something to do with the way am importing or exporting but can't resolve it yet.

Error on the app consuming the shared component:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

```
// App.js 
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "my-component-ui-library";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Button>Hello World!</Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Folder structure in the shared component library (omitted other irrelevant files)

```
.
├── src
│   ├── components
│   │   └── Button
│   │       ├── Button.js
│   │       └── index.js
│   └── index.js
├── .babelrc
└── webpack.config.js
```

Code

```
// src/components/Button/Button.js
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Button = ({ children, bg }) => (
  <button
    style={{
      padding: "10px 20px",
      border: "none",
      color: "white",
      fontSize: "16px",
      background: bg
    }}
  >
    {children}
  </button>
);

Button.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  bg: PropTypes.string
};

Button.defaultProps = {
  bg: "#24a7fd"
};

export default Button;

// src/components/Button/index.js
import Button from "./Button";

export default Button;

// src/components/index.js
export { default as Button } from "./Button";


//.babelrc
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}

// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/react"]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

// package.json
{
  "name": "my-component-ui-library",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "prepare": "npm run build"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using export with default keyword then importing the file will result you in a single variable.

For Example:

```
import Button from "my-component-ui-library";
```

Your code

```
import { Button } from "my-component-ui-library";
```

will work when you have multiple component exported from a file and you can import multiple components directly as

```
import { Button, XYZ } from "my-component-ui-library";
```

Comment: So is the problem here is that I only have a single component being exported but with more components, this problem will go away?

Comment: Your file has exported the button component as default hence you will need to import it as a single variable.

Comment: Which file? I am exporting in several places so not sure which file you mean.

Comment: I have changed App.js from `import { Button } from "my-component-ui-library";` to `import Button from "my-component-ui-library";` but the error is still present.